# How does Server Side Rendering works in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am new to `Next.js`, coming from an express/create-react-app background, and can't wrap my head around how SSR works in Next.js.

With SSR on expressJs, we would click on a link, and the server will send the corresponding ejs/pug/html page matching the new route. The state on the client is lost, as expected.

But with `Next.js`, the state on the client remains, which is not how I expect SSR to behave. Maybe SSR with Next is more similar to fetching an api for data, like the flow I am imagining below?

1. User visit a new page that requires SSR
2. `NextJs` calls `getServerSideProps` to grab some data(from api/db) and populate `props` for the page component.
3. Client's page component detects the new `props` and update itself(hydration?)

If someone can confirm or clarify would be appreciated.

Same page code for reference:

`paged.js`

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const sendGetRequest = async () => {
  try {
    const resp = await axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random");
    return resp.data.message;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

function Paged(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.dogstring}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const dogstring = await sendGetRequest();
  return {
    props: {
      dogstring: dogstring,
    },
  };
}

export default Paged;
```

Comment: _"Maybe SSR with Next is more similar to fetching an api for data"_ - Yeah, that's kinda what happens on client-side page navigations. When clicking on a link, you can see in the network tab a request to a `.json` endpoint which returns the result of running `getServerSideProps` for the given page as JSON. This is then used to populate the page on the client. Check out [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#technical-details-2) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are many posts available to compare `SSR` and `CSR` but I rather explain it in my words.

Let's assume there is a page (we didn't know about its implementation) for example *[www.sample.io](http://www.sample.io)*

With opening the *[www.sample.io](http://www.sample.io)* the client sends some HTTP/HTTPS requests (not API calls) to the webserver (usually `nginx`).

The webserver, serves that page so it sends the result to the client. This behavior is similar to `SSR` or `CSR`.

So, what are the differences?

In **CSR**, the webserver sends some source code to the client. The client (browser) parse them and draw `HTML` with the `CSS` styles and add the `Javascript` to the whole page.

In the **SSR**, the webserver sends a ready-to-show `HTML` with `CSS` and javascript. in other words, the server will parse the source code and draw the page then send the result to the client.

Other page functionalities like API calls,  and users interaction like input forms, are handled by the `Javascript` without significant differences in SSR or CSR.

Comment: Yes I know how SSR works in the traditional sense. When the server sends an html to the browser, the client refresh with the new page, which destroys the existing state on the client. With Next.js, the state remain intact when the browser receives the html file, and my question is about how Next.js makes this happen.